# How can I make available the XML file which is in drawable folder for custom button in my application? 

Tags: android, xml

I have created one xml under drawable like following but couldn't understand how can I make this available to my application?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#302226"
        android:endColor="#6D7B8D"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="6dp"
        android:top="6dp"
        android:right="6dp"
        android:bottom="6dp" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set this xml file in any view's background property in xml file.

```
android:background="@drawable/your_above_xml_file_name"
```

Comment: ok let me check it now! Thanks for your valuable time to help me.

Comment: Hei Chirag it works fine. Thanks for your help  really great. Have a great day.

Comment: sorry I did that! Ap kahna se? Ye lag tah he UP or Maharasthra right?

Answer (score 1):

```
 //yourfilename.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
 <gradient
    android:startColor="#302226"
    android:endColor="#6D7B8D"
    android:angle="45"/>
<padding android:left="6dp"
    android:top="6dp"
    android:right="6dp"
    android:bottom="6dp" />
<corners android:radius="20dp" />
```

```
  //temp.xml

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/temp"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dip"
  android:background="@drawable/yourfilename"
 >
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

set this file to background of any view for which u have created this file. like

```
android:background="@drawable/buttonbg"
```

where buttonbg.xml is the name of above xml which is kept in drawable.